# Is there a shorter way to write compound 'if' conditions?

Tags: c++, c, if-statement

Just **instead** of:

```
if  ( ch == 'A' || ch == 'B' || ch == 'C' || .....
```

For example, to do it **like**:

```
if  ( ch == 'A', 'B', 'C', ...
```

is there even a **shorter** way to summarize conditions?

Comment: No, there's no shorthand for this.

Comment: Maybe you want `isupper(ch)`?

Comment: If your values are consecutive as shown, `if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'C')` or wherever it goes to.

Comment: is this c++ or c? because there's a shorthand-ish way in c++ even if the things you're checking against aren't contiguous.

Comment: It was actually an exercise in my book where the user should enter a string and the program compute and print the value of the string like at the game scramble . i solved the problem so thanks to all of you.

Comment: "program compute and print the value of the string like at the game scramble" A cheap hack for this, in ASCII-land anyway, is an array of `int` eg: `int lettervalues[26] = {<values go here>};` and access with `lettervalues[letter-'A']`.

Comment: @user4581301 It was like ; Enter Word : hello ; scramble value : 7 ; each letter has a  determined value and it just computes every single letter and print the value of the whole word. like 3+ 1 + 1 + 1 + 1

Comment: Please remove either the C tag or the C++ tag to clearly identify which language you're using.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121960/discussion-on-question-by-optimusmaximus-is-there-a-way-to-write-nested-if-con).

Comment: At least a couple of times a year I wish C had Pascal's set operators ... Oh well ...

Answer (score 85, accepted):

[`strchr()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strchr.3.html) can be used to see if the character is in a list.

```
const char* list = "ABCXZ";
if (strchr(list, ch)) {
  // 'ch' is 'A', 'B', 'C', 'X', or 'Z'
}
```

Comment: Maybe that is personal style, but I would eliminate the intermediate `list` variable and directly pass the string as an argument.

Comment: @jaggedSpire Ok. Agreed, but... yeah, you're right.

Comment: @monkeyman79 You waiting tens of seconds for a reaction to a button isn't because people wrote code like this. It's because, when it was time to *actually* optimize, people didn't find the real bottlenecks correctly. Also, "awful response" was a bit harsh; the OP wasn't even asking about a performance bottleneck centered around this code. This is a 100% fine answer.

Comment: it's good if the characters are random, but not if they're contiguous

Comment: @L And yet, it works flawlessly with contiguous characters.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhú how would you determine if the characters are contiguous?

Comment: @M.M If the codepoint is contiguous in that charset

Comment: This quick and dirty solution actually has a problem: `ch = '\0'` will **also** match.  If you already know that `ch` cannot be null, that's OK, otherwise, it is a bug.  You can avoid this with: `if (memchr("ABCXY", ch, 5) { ... }`, which should be faster anyway.

Comment: @chqrlie Or, alternatively, `if (ch && strchr(list, ch)) { ... }` if you don't want to supply the length for whatever reason.

Comment: @artm: The question is closed as duplicate. Btw the `strchr()` and `memchr()` approaches share a common flaw: there are false positives if `ch` is not a `char`. To be strictly equivalent to the statements in the question, one should write `if (ch == (char)ch && ch && strchr(list, ch)) { ... }`

Answer (score 40):

In this case you could use a `switch`:

```
switch (ch) {
case 'A':
case 'B':
case 'C':
    // do something
    break;
case 'D':
case 'E':
case 'F':
    // do something else
    break;
...
}
```

While this is slightly more verbose than using `strchr`, it doesn't involve any function calls.  It also works for both C and C++.

Note that the alternate syntax you suggested won't work as you might expect because of the use of the comma operator:

```
if  ( ch == 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' )
```

This first compares `ch` to `'A'` and then discards the result.  Then `'B'` is evaluated and discarded, then `'C'`, and so forth until `'F'` is evaluated.  Then `'F'` becomes the value of the conditional.  Since any non-zero value evaluated to true in a boolean context (and `'F'` is non-zero), then the above expression will always be true.

Comment: How is this not the accepted answer?

Comment: It doesn't work in every way. Only if the cases are known at runtime. It's also not an if statement based on boolean, it's a lookup operation.

Answer (score 34):

Templates allow us to express ourselves in this way:

```
if (range("A-F").contains(ch)) { ... }
```

It requires a little plumbing, which you can put in a library.

This actually compiles out to be incredibly efficient (at least on gcc and clang).

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

namespace detail {
    template<class T>
    struct range
    {
        constexpr range(T first, T last)
        : _begin(first), _end(last)
        {}

        constexpr T begin() const { return _begin; }
        constexpr T end() const { return _end; }

        template<class U>
        constexpr bool contains(const U& u) const
        {
            return _begin <= u and u <= _end;
        }

    private:
        T _begin;
        T _end;
    };

    template<class...Ranges>
    struct ranges
    {
        constexpr ranges(Ranges...ranges) : _ranges(std::make_tuple(ranges...)) {}

        template<class U>
        struct range_check
        {
            template<std::size_t I>
            bool contains_impl(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>,
                               const U& u,
                               const std::tuple<Ranges...>& ranges) const
            {
                return std::get<I>(ranges).contains(u)
                or contains_impl(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I+1>(),u, ranges);
            }

            bool contains_impl(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, sizeof...(Ranges)>,
                               const U& u,
                               const std::tuple<Ranges...>& ranges) const
            {
                return false;
            }


            constexpr bool operator()(const U& u, std::tuple<Ranges...> const& ranges) const
            {
                return contains_impl(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0>(), u, ranges);
            }
        };

        template<class U>
        constexpr bool contains(const U& u) const
        {
            range_check<U> check {};
            return check(u, _ranges);
        }

        std::tuple<Ranges...> _ranges;
    };
}

template<class T>
constexpr auto range(T t) { return detail::range<T>(t, t); }

template<class T>
constexpr auto range(T from, T to) { return detail::range<T>(from, to); }

// this is the little trick which turns an ascii string into
// a range of characters at compile time. It's probably a bit naughty
// as I am not checking syntax. You could write "ApZ" and it would be
// interpreted as "A-Z".
constexpr auto range(const char (&s)[4])
{
    return range(s[0], s[2]);
}

template<class...Rs>
constexpr auto ranges(Rs...rs)
{
    return detail::ranges<Rs...>(rs...);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << range(1,7).contains(5) << std::endl;
    std::cout << range("a-f").contains('b') << std::endl;

    auto az = ranges(range('a'), range('z'));
    std::cout << az.contains('a') << std::endl;
    std::cout << az.contains('z') << std::endl;
    std::cout << az.contains('p') << std::endl;

    auto rs = ranges(range("a-f"), range("p-z"));
    for (char ch = 'a' ; ch <= 'z' ; ++ch)
    {
        std::cout << ch << rs.contains(ch) << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

expected output:

```
1
1
1
1
0
a1 b1 c1 d1 e1 f1 g0 h0 i0 j0 k0 l0 m0 n0 o0 p1 q1 r1 s1 t1 u1 v1 w1 x1 y1 z1
```

For reference, here was my original answer:

```
template<class X, class Y>
bool in(X const& x, Y const& y)
{
    return x == y;
}

template<class X, class Y, class...Rest>
bool in(X const& x, Y const& y, Rest const&...rest)
{
    return in(x, y) or in(x, rest...);
}

int main()
{
    int ch = 6;
    std::cout << in(ch, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7) << std::endl;

    std::string foo = "foo";
    std::cout << in(foo, "bar", "foo", "baz") << std::endl;

    std::cout << in(foo, "bar", "baz") << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but i don't really understand the whole code because i am not so deep into programming and this is c++

Comment: This is nice, but looks like a huge overkill if only `char` comparsion in needed.

Comment: Deep down inside, everybody wants to write code in LISP.

Comment: Deep down inside, everybody wants to wear the paint off their angle bracket keys.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: The important point is the same code can be reused the *next* time you want to do "is the thing in the list" too.

Comment: Why not `bool in(X const& x, Y const& y, Rest const&...rest)
{
    return x == y or in(x, rest...);
}` without the `bool in(X const& x, Y const& y)` definition above that looks like a rename of `==` ?

Comment: @Caridorc you need a termination condition, but by all means remove the termination case and see what happens.

Comment: @RichardHodges Error: `templ.cpp:6:35:   recursively required from ‘bool in(const X&, const Y&, const Rest& ...) [with X = int; Y = int; Rest = {int, int, int, int, int}]’
templ.cpp:6:35:   required from ‘bool in(const X&, const Y&, const Rest& ...) [with X = int; Y = int; Rest = {int, int, int, int, int, int}]’
templ.cpp:12:38:   required from here
templ.cpp:6:35: error: no matching function for call to ‘in(const int&)’
     return x == y or in(x, rest...);`
                                   ^
# It continues...   This is a hard error message to understand, any clues?

Comment: @Caridorc it can't find the base case.

Comment: @jaggedSpire my reasoning was that being the first `in` definition and `==` equal I could substitute the one for the other, but clearly I was wrong on something...

Comment: @jaggedSpire I get it now, the template reduces arguement number more and more so it will be called `in(a, b)` at the end and if `in(a, b)` is not defined that inordinate error message will be generated

Comment: @Caridorc it's one of the fundamental lessons in writing recursive template expansions. We won't need them after c++17 as we'll have operator folding.

Comment: @RichardHodges do you mean that the lesson is to always write a base case or that the lesson is that the errors are unreadable?

Comment: @Caridorc haha! probably both. Having a termination case certainly helps prevent the unreadable errors.

Comment: @hyde Who cares, really. The sentiment of the OPs comment was pretty clear and bears no further pedantic analysis. Nothing is to be gained by your line of questioning except for unwelcome comment noise.

Answer (score 14):

If you need to check a character against an arbitrary set of characters, you could try writing this:

```
std::set<char> allowed_chars = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'G', 'Q', '7', 'z'};
if(allowed_chars.find(ch) != allowed_chars.end()) {
    /*...*/
}
```

Comment: a `static const` `set` maybe?

Comment: Unless you are dealing with very, very big character sets (more than 256), that must be the slowest possible way to do this.

Comment: @MikeMB Well, it's probably faster than `strchr`, and it's obvious in code what it's doing without comments. AND it extends better for runtime determination of which characters are allowed. The only real disadvantage is probably increased memory use.

Comment: @Xirema: Why do you think it is faster than `strchr`? And why would the `strchr` version require comments?

Comment: @MikeMB Runs in O(log(n)) time, whereas `strchr` runs in O(n) time, where 'n' is the number of characters in the set. Theoretically, if one were to use `std::unordered_set` the runtime becomes O(1), though I think the constant time + building operations on the set would, as you suggested, make it slow for small character sets. But `std::set` is pretty fast to build, so it's less of an issue there.

Comment: I would use `std::set::count()` instead of verbose iterator comparison

Comment: @slava Also an option. I've been avoiding `count` because Visual Studio has some serious performance regressions in that codepath that haven't been fixed yet.

Comment: @Xirema: I very much doubt that asymptotic complexity matters here and `std::set` is a pretty inefficient data structure for storing characters (Chandler expained this imho quite well on cppcon14: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fHNmRkzxHWs). If you have time you might want to have a look at the my pseudo-"benchmark": https://ideone.com/h6WxBI. On my machine `strchr` outperforms the `std::set` solution by a factor of 2 or more, but that is probably highly system, compiler and benchmark specific. It is actually not as bad as I expected.

Comment: @Xirema O(n) vs. O(log(n)) for a set of 9 items is irrelevant here, especially considering overhead and presumed other processing. If you're trying to make a performance argument for some reason, use a `bool charIsAllowed[256]` lookup table with `unsigned char`s for O(1) instead.

Comment: @MikeMB: This may well be slow, but the problem is literally "I want a short solution" not "I need a fast solution".

Comment: @Hurkly: The nice thing is that strchr is both shorter and faster. But yes, you are right, it doesn't really matter and the performance difference is much smaller than I expectet. The nice thing is that it works with almost any datatype - not only with chars.

Comment: You want `std::unordered_set`, not `std::set`. The hash set will give you O(1) lookup.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus As long as we remember that the `1` in `O(1)` doesn't mean `1 cpu cycle` :) Bear in mind that, since it wasn't declared static, the function has to be built every time the function is entered. Either way, strcmp beats the pants off of it: https://godbolt.org/g/6XPp7P

Comment: @kfsone Sure, but `static const` was already mentioned. There's going to be a crossover point in size of the set where `strchr` is slower (even if it compiles into a nice small loop), at least if you offload the set creation to compile time.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus yes, in my experience the crossing point between a linear search and a set lookup (either tree or hashmap) happens in the order of a few dozens of elements. Also, a linear scan with `strchr` is very cache-efficient, while a search in a tree usually isn't, not to mention a hashmap lookup.

Answer (score 14):

Yet another answer on this overly-answered question, which I'm just including for completeness. Between all of the answers here you should find *something* that works in your application.

So another option is a lookup table:

```
// On initialization:
bool isAcceptable[256] = { false };
isAcceptable[(unsigned char)'A'] = true;
isAcceptable[(unsigned char)'B'] = true;
isAcceptable[(unsigned char)'C'] = true;

// When you want to check:
char c = ...;
if (isAcceptable[(unsigned char)c]) {
   // it's 'A', 'B', or 'C'.
}
```

Scoff at the C-style static casts if you must, but they do get the job done. I suppose you could use an `std::vector<bool>` if arrays keep you up at night. You can also use types besides `bool`. But you get the idea.

Obviously this becomes cumbersome with e.g. `wchar_t`, and virtually unusable with multibyte encodings. But for your `char` example, or for anything that lends itself to a lookup table, it'll do. YMMV.

Comment: Might be worth an edit to slip in a mention of `std::map` for those sparse, multibyte cases.

Comment: And `256` should be replaced by `1<<CHAR_BIT` in general.

Comment: ^^^ Thar be some fine comments.

Answer (score 12):

Similarly to the C `strchr` answer, In C++ you can construct a string and check the character against its contents:

```
#include <string>
...
std::string("ABCDEFGIKZ").find(c) != std::string::npos;
```

The above will return `true` for `'F'` and `'Z'` but `false` for `'z'` or `'O'`. This code does not assume contiguous representation of characters.

This works because [`std::string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) returns `std::string::npos` when it can't find the character in the string.

<sup>[*Live on Coliru*](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5af8f8f658601370)</sup>

*Edit:*

There's another C++ method which *doesn't* involve dynamic allocation, but does involve an even longer piece of code:

```
#include <algorithm> // std::find
#include <iterator> // std::begin and std::end
...
char const chars[] = "ABCDEFGIKZ";
return std::find(std::begin(chars), std::end(chars), c) != std::end(chars);
```

This works similarly to the first code snippet: [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) searches the given range and returns a specific value if the item isn't found. Here, said specific value is the range's end.

<sup>[*Live on Coliru*](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/beb5193e6fa51a1a)</sup>

Comment: It is telling, that the c++-ish version is a lot longer and possibly requires a dynamic memory alllocation to do the same thing as the c-style version. Luckily most of the c-standard library is also part of the c++ standard library.

Comment: Indeed. One could also do a `std::find` on the same static array as the C version, which would eliminate the dynamic allocation at the price of increased length.

Comment: @MikeMB added the amusingly verbose alternative without dynamic allocation

Comment: I'm really looking forward to the day when one can use things like `std::string_view` and ranges in SO answers ;)

Comment: @MikeMB It's going to be wonderful :)

Comment: The second example needs `#include <iterator>` to ensure `std::begin` and `std::end` are available.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy fixed. Thanks!

Comment: Disadvantage of the first method: it has to create a string object every time. Sadly the std::find solution doesn't generate code quite as efficient as strchr: https://godbolt.org/g/aRPgbU

Answer (score 6):

One option is the `unordered_set`. Put the characters of interest into the set. Then just check the count of the character in question:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  unordered_set<char> characters;
  characters.insert('A');
  characters.insert('B');
  characters.insert('C');
  // ...

  if (characters.count('A')) {
    cout << "found" << endl;
  } else {
    cout << "not found" << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

There is solution to your problem, not in language but in coding practices - **Refactoring**.

I'm quite sure that readers will find this answer very unorthodox, but - Refactoring can, and is used often to, hide a messy piece of code behind a method call. That method can be cleaned later or it can be left as it is.

You can create the following method:

```
private bool characterIsValid(char ch) {
    return (ch == 'A' || ch == 'B' || ch == 'C' || ..... );
}
```

and then this method can be called in a short form as:

```
if (characterIsValid(ch)) ...
```

Reuse that method with so many checks and only returning a boolean, anywhere.

Comment: `private bool methodName()` looks neither like C nor like C++...

Comment: Code refactorings are language agnostic.

Answer (score 3):

For a simple and effective solution, you can use `memchr()`:

```
#include <string.h>

const char list[] = "ABCXZ";
if (memchr(list, ch, sizeof(list) - 1)) {
    // 'ch' is 'A', 'B', 'C', 'X', or 'Z'
}
```

Note that `memchr()` is better suited than `strchr()` for this task as `strchr()` would find the null character `'\0'` at the end of the string, which is incorrect for most cases.

If the list is dynamic or external and its length is not provided, the `strchr()` approach is better, but you should check if `ch` is different from `0` as `strchr()` would find it at the end of the string:

```
#include <string.h>

extern char list[];
if (ch && strchr(list, ch)) {
    // 'ch' is one of the characters in the list
}
```

Another more efficient but less terse **C99** specific solution uses an array:

```
#include <limits.h>

const char list[UCHAR_MAX + 1] = { ['A'] = 1, ['B'] = 1, ['C'] = 1, ['X'] = 1, ['Z'] = 1 };
if (list[(unsigned char)ch]) {
    /* ch is one of the matching characters */
}
```

Note however that all of the above solutions assume `ch` to have `char` type. If `ch` has a different type, they would accept false positives. Here is how to fix this:

```
#include <string.h>

extern char list[];
if (ch == (char)ch && ch && strchr(list, ch)) {
    // 'ch' is one of the characters in the list
}
```

Furthermore, beware of pitfalls if you are comparing `unsigned char` values:

```
unsigned char ch = 0xFF;
if (ch == '\xFF') {
    /* test fails if `char` is signed by default */
}
if (memchr("\xFF", ch, 1)) {
    /* test succeeds in all cases, is this OK? */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For this specific case you can use the fact that `char` is an integer and test for a range:

```
if(ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'C')
{
    ...
}
```

But in general this is not possible unfortunately. If you want to compress your code just use a boolean function

```
if(compare_char(ch))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Please state **explicitly** the assumptions that this code makes. It is not portable.

Comment: That first test will not work if the range of characters is larger and you're working with EBCDIC, not ASCII.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie If there's z/OS developers reading this question, we've got bigger problems.

Answer (score 2):

The [X-Y answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) on the vast majority of modern systems is don't bother.

You can take advantage of the fact that practically every character encoding used today stores the alphabet in one sequentially-ordered contiguous block. A is followed by B, B is followed by C, etc... on to Z. This allows you to do simple math tricks on letters to convert the letter to a number. For example the letter C minus the letter A , 'C' - 'A', is 2, the distance between c and a.

Some character sets, EBCDIC was discussed in the comments above, are not sequential or contiguous for reasons that are out of scope for discussion here. They are rare, but occasionally you will find one. When you do... Well, most of the other answers here provide suitable solutions.

We can use this to make a mapping of letter values to letters with a simple array:

```
//                    a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p, q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y, z
int lettervalues[] = {1,3,3,2,1,4,2,4,1,8,5,1,3,1,1,3,10,1,1,1,1,4,4,8,4,10};
```

So `'c' - 'a'` is 2 and `lettervalues[2]` will result in 3, the letter value of C.

No if statements or conditional logic required what-so-ever. All the debugging you need to do is proof reading `lettervalues` to make sure you entered the correct values.

As you study more in C++, you will learn that `lettervalues` should be `static` (current translation unit-only access) and `const` (cannot be changed), possibly `constexpr` (cannot be changed and fixed at compile time). If you don't know what I'm talking about, don't worry. You'll cover all three later. If not, google them. All are very useful tools.

Using this array could be as simple as

```
int ComputeWordScore(std::string in)
{
    int score = 0;
    for (char ch: in) // for all characters in string
    {
        score += lettervalues[ch - 'a'];
    }
    return score;
}
```

But this has two fatal blind spots:

The first is capital letters. Sorry Ayn Rand, but 'A' is not 'a', and `'A'-'a'` is not zero. This can be solved by using [`std::tolower`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower) or [`std::toupper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper) to convert all input to a known case.

```
int ComputeWordScore(std::string in)
{
    int score = 0;
    for (char ch: in) // for all characters in string
    {
        score += lettervalues[std::tolower(ch) - 'a'];
    }
    return score;
}
```

The other is input of characters that aren't letters. For example, '1'. `'a' - '1'` will result in an array index that is not in the array. This is bad. If you're lucky your program will crash, but anything could happen, including looking as though your program works. Read up on [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) for more.

Fortunately this also has a simple fix: Only compute the score for good input. You can test for valid alphabet characters with [`std::isalpha`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha).

```
int ComputeWordScore(std::string in)
{
    int score = 0;
    for (char ch: in) // for all characters in string
    {
        if (std::isalpha(ch))
        {
            score += lettervalues[std::tolower(ch) - 'a'];
        }
        else
        {
            // do something that makes sense here. 
        }
    }
    return score;
}
```

My something else would be `return -1;`. -1 is an impossible word score, so anyone who calls `ComputeWordScore` can test for -1 and reject the user's input. What they do with it is not `ComputeWordScore`'s problem. Generally the stupider you can make a function, the better, and errors should be handled by the closest piece of code that has all the information needed to make a decision. In this case, whatever read in the string would likely be tasked with deciding what to do with bad strings and `ComputeWordScore` can keep on computing word scores.

Comment: The answer doesn't look very useful. First it starts with an unportable assumption (although explicitly explained). Then it introduces a solution which is prone to errors: needs careful proof-reading, can have buffer overflows. After that it also introduces a bunch of irrelevant keywords. After several bug fixes the final solution doesn't look reliable at all.

Comment: Looks be damned. It is reliable. The irrelevant keywords, assuming you know what they mean and how to use them, make it more reliable. The table-based look-up is very easy to modify and maintain. I will grant you it requires some care in ensuring the correct values are assigned to the correct letters, but this is the case in any solution. Here all of the numbers are in one place and easily checked. There are no bug fixes; just the minimum testing required to validate user input. If you don't test everything a user gives you, you're a fool.

Comment: That's why downvoters usually don't comment. Because it's easy to be damned by the poster insulted by the downvote.

Comment: @Ruslan:  "X be damned" is an [English idiom](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/199689/alternate-phrase-for-be-damned-to-avoid-profanity).  Here `X` is "Looks", so the phrase means "How the code looks is unimportant to me."

Comment: @Ruslan My apologies for any misinterpretation. I neglected to consider the international nature of Stack Overflow in my response. The only intentional malice in my comment is directed at those who do not verify data coming from unreliable or hostile sources.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the terse versions have been covered, so I will cover the optimized cases with some helper macros to make them a little more terse.

It just so happens that if your range falls within your number of bits per long that you can combine all of your constants using a bitmask and just check that your value falls in the range and the variable's bitmask is non-zero when bitwise-anded with the constant bitmask.

```
/* This macro assumes the bits will fit in a long integer type,
 * if it needs to be larger (64 bits on x32 etc...),
 * you can change the shifted 1ULs to 1ULL or if range is > 64 bits,
 * split it into multiple ranges or use SIMD
 * It also assumes that a0 is the lowest and a9 is the highest,
 * You may want to add compile time assert that:
 * a9 (the highest value) - a0 (the lowest value) < max_bits
 * and that a1-a8 fall within a0 to a9
 */
#define RANGE_TO_BITMASK_10(a0,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9) \
  (1 | (1UL<<((a1)-(a0))) | (1UL<<((a2)-(a0))) | (1UL<<((a3)-(a0))) | \
  (1UL<<((a4)-(a0))) | (1UL<<((a5)-(a0))) | (1UL<<((a6)-(a0))) | \
  (1UL<<((a7)-(a0))) | (1UL<<((a8)-(a0))) | (1UL<<((a9)-(a0))) )

/*static inline*/ bool checkx(int x){
    const unsigned long bitmask = /* assume 64 bits */
        RANGE_TO_BITMASK_10('A','B','C','F','G','H','c','f','y','z');
    unsigned temp = (unsigned)x-'A';
    return ( ( temp <= ('z'-'A') ) && !!( (1ULL<<temp) & bitmask ) );
}
```

Since all of a# values are constants, they will be combined into 1 bitmask at compile time.  That leaves 1 subtraction and 1 compare for the range, 1 shift and 1 bitwise and ... unless the compiler can optimize further, it turns out clang can (it uses the bit test instruction BTQ):

```
checkx:                                 # @checkx
        addl    $-65, %edi
        cmpl    $57, %edi
        ja      .LBB0_1
        movabsq $216172936732606695, %rax # imm = 0x3000024000000E7
        btq     %rdi, %rax
        setb    %al
        retq
.LBB0_1:
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        retq
```

It may look like more code on the C side, but if you are looking to optimize, this looks like it may be worth it on the assembly side.  I'm sure someone could get creative with the macro to make it more useful in a real programming situations than this "proof of concept".

That will get a little complex as a macro, so here is an alternative set of macros to setup a C99 lookup table.

```
#include <limits.h>
#define INIT_1(v,a) [ a ] = v
#define INIT_2(v,a,...) [ a ] = v, INIT_1(v, __VA_ARGS__)
#define INIT_3(v,a,...) [ a ] = v, INIT_2(v, __VA_ARGS__)
#define INIT_4(v,a,...) [ a ] = v, INIT_3(v, __VA_ARGS__)
#define INIT_5(v,a,...) [ a ] = v, INIT_4(v, __VA_ARGS__)
#define INIT_6(v,a,...) [ a ] = v, INIT_5(v, __VA_ARGS__)
#define INIT_7(v,a,...) [ a ] = v, INIT_6(v, __VA_ARGS__)
#define INIT_8(v,a,...) [ a ] = v, INIT_7(v, __VA_ARGS__)
#define INIT_9(v,a,...) [ a ] = v, INIT_8(v, __VA_ARGS__)
#define INIT_10(v,a,...) [ a ] = v, INIT_9(v, __VA_ARGS__)
#define ISANY10(x,...) ((const unsigned char[UCHAR_MAX+1]){ \
                          INIT_10(-1, __VA_ARGS__) \
                       })[x]

bool checkX(int x){
  return ISANY10(x,'A','B','C','F','G','H','c','f','y','z');
}
```

This method will use a (typically) 256 byte table and a lookup that reduces to something like the following in gcc:

```
checkX:
        movslq  %edi, %rdi  # x, x
        cmpb    $0, C.2.1300(%rdi)      #, C.2
        setne   %al   #, tmp93
        ret
```

NOTE: Clang doesn't fare as well on the lookup table in this method because it sets up const tables that occur inside functions on the stack on each function call, so you would want to use INIT_10 to initialize a `static const unsigned char [UCHAR_MAX+1]` outside of the function to achieve similar optimization to gcc.