# Optimizing an if statement with over 50 OR's ( || )

Tags: c++, if-statement, optimization

Okay, so I'm doing some stuff involving keyboard input. I now have a giant function like this:

```
return key == BB_KEY_SPACE ||
        key == BB_KEY_ZERO ||
        key == BB_KEY_ONE ||
        key == BB_KEY_TWO ||
        key == BB_KEY_THREE ||
        key == BB_KEY_FOUR ||
        key == BB_KEY_FIVE ||
        key == BB_KEY_SIX ||
        key == BB_KEY_SEVEN ||
        key == BB_KEY_EIGHT ||
        key == BB_KEY_NINE ||
        key == BB_KEY_A ||
        key == BB_KEY_B ||
        key == BB_KEY_C ||
        key == BB_KEY_D ||
        key == BB_KEY_E ||
        key == BB_KEY_F ||
        key == BB_KEY_G ||
        key == BB_KEY_H ||
        key == BB_KEY_I ||
        key == BB_KEY_J ||
        key == BB_KEY_K ||
        key == BB_KEY_L ||
        key == BB_KEY_M ||
        key == BB_KEY_N ||
        key == BB_KEY_O ||
        key == BB_KEY_P ||
        key == BB_KEY_Q ||
        key == BB_KEY_R ||
        key == BB_KEY_S ||
        key == BB_KEY_T ||
        key == BB_KEY_U ||
        key == BB_KEY_V ||
        key == BB_KEY_W ||
        key == BB_KEY_X ||
        key == BB_KEY_Y ||
        key == BB_KEY_Z ||
        key == BB_KEY_NUMPAD0 ||
        key == BB_KEY_NUMPAD1 ||
        key == BB_KEY_NUMPAD2 ||
        key == BB_KEY_NUMPAD3 ||
        key == BB_KEY_NUMPAD4 ||
        key == BB_KEY_NUMPAD5 ||
        key == BB_KEY_NUMPAD6 ||
        key == BB_KEY_NUMPAD7 ||
        key == BB_KEY_NUMPAD8 ||
        key == BB_KEY_NUMPAD9 ||
        key == BB_KEY_MULTIPLY ||
        key == BB_KEY_PLUS ||
        key == BB_KEY_SEPERATOR ||
        key == BB_KEY_MINUS ||
        key == BB_KEY_DECIMAL ||
        key == BB_KEY_DIVIDE ||
        key == BB_KEY_OEM1 ||
        key == BB_KEY_OEMPLUS ||
        key == BB_KEY_OEMCOMMA ||
        key == BB_KEY_OEMMINUS ||
        key == BB_KEY_OEMPERIOD ||
        key == BB_KEY_OEM2 ||
        key == BB_KEY_OEM3 ||
        key == BB_KEY_OEM4 ||
        key == BB_KEY_OEM5 ||
        key == BB_KEY_OEM6 ||
        key == BB_KEY_OEM7 ||
        key == BB_KEY_OEM8 ||
        key == BB_KEY_OEM102;`
```

Is there a good way to optimize this? I am assuming it takes a bit of processing power to verify all of this if-statement stuff. When looking at diagnostics it seems it's taking up a bit of time too. I'm wondering if there is a smarter way of doing this..

Comment: Try asking these guys: [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) - they'll be happy to suggest improvements!

Comment: How big is the list of what it *doesn't* equal?

Comment: What type is `key`?

Comment: @Galik The list that it doesn't equal to is even bigger. Hundreds of options.

Comment: You can save all those keys in an array, then loop through it, and return true on the first match, return false if it fails to find a match.  It won't make it too much shorter, but at least it'll get rid of all those `||`, and the actual processing code will just be the loop and return statement.

Comment: If you are sure about consecutive range, you can do groupings like `(key >= BB_KEY_A && key <= BB_KEY_Z) || ...`

Comment: Optimizing this is something the compiler should do for you. Have you enabled the optimization options? How does the generated code look like?

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe That's the thing. It needs to be very performant. This cannot ever be a performance bottleneck, so I'm looking for ways to improve it.

Comment: Do not optimize something that you don't already *know* is a bottleneck.  PROFILE FIRST.

Comment: @Cody I'll see how that ship sails.. I'll report back soon-ish.

Comment: There is an entire *family* of questions and answers for this, one of them being the recently asked [Is there a shorter way to write compound if conditions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39150884/is-there-a-shorter-way-to-write-compound-if-conditions) Poking around the duplicates and linked posts should grant you a veritable *forest* of answers.

Comment: @dvix It's a char. There is no way of remapping the value to let them all be under a certain value or be in a certain range, unfortunately..

Comment: Do you do this more then just the one time?

Comment: @RikoOphorst Then it has 256 possible values. You can simply define a global `char arr[256];` and initialize it with `arr[BB_KEY_SPACE] = 1; /* same for all other BB_* values */` and the rest of values set to `0`. Then `return arr[key];`.

Comment: If space is an issue you could use `const std::vector<bool> arr(256)` instead of a `char arr[256]` because that packs the data into actual bits. It should be `1/8th` the size.

Comment: I think you'll be surprised, if you look at the optimised assembler output, at how efficient your compiler has already made this test. It will have identified sequences of codes and tested only the boundaries of the sequence.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Making use of the additional information gleaned from the comments that `key` is a `char` type, there are 256 possible values for `key`. The return value for each of the possible values of `key` can be stored into a global array indexed by `key`, and retrieved by simply returning the `key`'th element of the array.

```
char arr[256] = { 0 };
arr[BB_KEY_SPACE] = 1;
arr[BB_KEY_ZERO] = 1;
/* ... */
arr[BB_KEY_OEM102] = 1;

bool f(char key)
{
    return arr[(unsigned)key] != 0; /* == 1 for the BB_KEY_* values */
}
```

---

[ *EDIT* ] As originally suggested by @Galik in a comment, some memory could be saved (at a negligible speed penalty) by using a `std::vector<bool> arr(256);` instead of the char array.

---

[ *EDIT #2* ] As commented by @Hurkyl and @Danh below, given that `arr` is an array of known, fixed size, `std::bitset` could (should?) be used instead of `std::vector<bool>`.

While this is entirely correct, the choice between them has been the subject of discussions and arguments for a long time. Searching SO and/or google'ing for `std::bitset vs std::vector<bool>` will find a number of opinions on both sides.

Comment: This is the most performant option of them all. Sacrificing a bit of memory, this has the absolute quickest performance. Thanks!

Comment: While this answer works, it is ugly. You should really look into *hash functions*, because that is what this is, and there are cleaner ways to do it.

Comment: This could also be implemented as a bit vector using only 256 / 8 = 32 bytes.

Comment: @RikoOphorst If you want to save a little memory (with a *very* slight speed penalty) consider Galik's comment about using `const std::vector<bool> arr(256)`.

Comment: Are you sure that `char` is unsigned? Using a `char` as an array index usually produces a warning.

Comment: @RolandIllig Fair point, thank you. I added an `unsigned` cast.

Comment: Maybe consider adding `std::vector<bool> arr(256);` to the answer as a space optimization with likely not very much performance penalty.

Comment: @MattWay Will look into it!

Comment: @MattWay Won't argue the `ugly` part ;-) yet I'd point that that's precisely how many CRTs implement the `isdigit`, `isalpha`, etc classification functions.

Comment: @Galik Thanks. Done.

Comment: `bitset` is probably better than `vector<bool>` here.

Comment: @Hurkyl Might be, but that's unlikely to make much of a difference in what's ultimately a very small set here, plus I don't want to steer this into an unrelated `bitset` vs. `vector<bool>` debate of which there are several on SO already.

Comment: std::vector<bool> is deprecated from C++11 and will be removed in upcoming standard. std::bitset please

Comment: @Danh Reference, please? I am aware of longstanding discussions/controversies, but not that `vector<bool>` would have actually been deprecated.

Comment: My bad, it was proposed to be deprecated by Herb Sutter but it's rejected http://www.gotw.ca/publications/N1185.pdf

Comment: Anyway, he need a static sized data, std::bit_set should be preferred. Just like std::array is preferred over std::vector if the size is constant

Comment: @Danh Thanks. Updated answer with the `std::bitset` option.

Answer (score 11):

Turn this into a switch statement:

```
 switch (key) {
 case BB_KEY_SPACE:
 case BB_KEY_ZERO:
 case BB_KEY_ONE:
      // ... and so on
```

Your compiler is very smart. If these literal constants form just a handful of ranges of consecutive integer values, the compiler will handle optimizing this into a small number of comparisons, to implement the bounds checking for each range of values.

And if not, the compiler will likely use a few other heuristical tools in order to come up with an optimized set of comparisons.

It's also possible that a modern compiler will be smart enough to use the same optimizations for the long-winded `if()` version, but using the `switch` statement helps the compiler "see the light of day", and figure out the best way to crunch through all of this.

Answer (score 2):

If there are ranges:

```
if ((key >= SOME_MIN && key <= SOME_MAX) ||
    (key >= SOM_OTHER_MIN && key <= SOME_OTHER_MAX) ...
```

Works but you have to dive into the constants which is bad.

I'd put the matching key constants into a set and then I can just say something like `if (keySet.contains(key))`. Of course you set the set up once at startup, not every time you want to check a key.

Comment: *Works but you have to dive into the constants which is bad.* honestly, if someone designed A-Z or 0-9 constants not to be contiguous (or if the library decided to change this from one version to another) you should just run away from such a toolkit. "natural" are the way to go - more efficient and - most importantly - way more readable than to cite every letter from A to Z.

Comment: @MatteoItalia You're probably right, but who knows. A sensible lib should give you equivalents of `isalpha()` etc anyway...

Answer (score 1):

Break it down.
You want functions like

key_isnumpad(), key_isalpha() and so on.

So the function tuurns into

i`f(key_isnumpad() || key_isalpha() || ...)`

and becomes much more readable. That will actually slow it down unless you have a good optimiser.
But you can then write the individual functions better, with a range (assuming numbers are contiguous).

Finally place the most likely case first.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way, using templates. For fun and education mostly. But maybe there's a use case if you're maintaining, for example, a number of properties related to each key-code value:

```
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>
#include <limits>
#include <utility>

//
// define our enum of codes
//
enum key_code : char
{
    BB_KEY_SPACE = ' ',
    BB_KEY_ZERO = '0',
    BB_KEY_ONE,
    BB_KEY_TWO,
    BB_KEY_THREE,
//  ...etc...
};

//
// by default we don't want the code to match
//    
template <key_code K> const bool is_wanted = false;

//
// but for these codes we do want a match (extend as needed)
//
template <> const bool is_wanted<BB_KEY_SPACE> = true;
template <> const bool is_wanted<BB_KEY_ZERO> = true;
template <> const bool is_wanted<BB_KEY_ONE> = true;
template <> const bool is_wanted<BB_KEY_TWO> = true;

//
// constexpr function to work out the minimum value of the enum
// (in case it's a signed type)
//    
static constexpr std::size_t min_value() { 
  return std::numeric_limits<std::underlying_type_t<key_code>>::min();
}

//
// constexpr function to work out the maximum value of the enum
// (in case it's a signed type)
//    
static constexpr std::size_t max_value() { 
  return std::numeric_limits<std::underlying_type_t<key_code>>::max();
}

//
// constexpr function to work out the extent of the enum
// so we can build an array to represent the test for every value
//    
static constexpr std::size_t to_index(key_code k)
{
  return std::size_t (int(k) - min_value());
}
//
// convenience function to find the correct position in our array
// for a given key code
//    
static constexpr std::size_t to_index(key_code k)
{
  return std::size_t (int(k) + min_value());
}


namespace detail {
  //
  // this function builds an array of bools. Index positions for
  // enum values which have been specialised above will be true
  // all others will be false
  //
  template<std::size_t...Is>
  static constexpr auto make_wanted_array(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
  -> std::array<bool, range_size()>
  {
    return 
    {
      is_wanted<static_cast<key_code>(Is - min_value())>...
    };
  }
}

//
// interface version simply calls the impl having constructed the
// correct index sequence
//    
static constexpr auto make_wanted_array()
-> std::array<bool, range_size()>
{
  return detail::make_wanted_array(std::make_index_sequence<range_size()>());
}

//
// this is the function to test whether a key is valid or not
bool valid_key(key_code k)
{
  // this will be done at compile time. There is zero runtime overhead.
  static constexpr auto wanted_array = make_wanted_array();
  // this is simply a load from memory address with register offset
  return wanted_array[to_index(k)];
}
```

Here is the assembler emitted for `valid_key` from gcc5.3 compiled with -O2:

```
valid_key(key_code):
        movsx   rdi, dil
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR valid_key(key_code)::wanted_array[rdi+128]
        ret
```

Note that it's adjusting by +128. This is because, in this case, the enum is a signed type so the index must be converted to be an unsigned value with base 0.

Answer (score -1):

First and foremost, do you **really** need to optimise this now? Even if you do, I doubt that it is your primary bottleneck. Anyway with that said, it at the very least doesn't look pretty. To frame your question in another light, you are basically asking, *how do I perform an if check on a potentially random set of values?*

As you know the values in advance, your task then is to model the *random* data, into something more semantically useful. As mentioned in the comments and answers, you can expose properties of the data like ranges (however, the compiler might be able to manage that).

The best optimisation in my opinion here is to implement a [Hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function).