# How can I define a macro that tests if a given character is a vowel?

Tags: c, macros

The following, code snippet does not give compilation error, but it does not give the expected output either, though this could be done in simple if-else way but I wanted to do it using macros. Here `c` is a character variable.

```
#define VOWELS 'a' || 'e' || 'i' || 'o' || 'u' || 'A' || 'E' || 'I' || 'O' || '
if (c == VOWELS) {
   printf("vowel = %c\n", c);
}
```

Comment: I suppose you could always just do the preprocessing, or even hand-substitute this yourself and see what is generated. `if (c == 'a' || 'e' || 'i' || ....)` is the result. If you hand-typed that out, it wouldn't work as desired either, so the use of a macro is somewhat a formality. So ask yourself, how would you change that expanded expression to be what you want? Then ask whether it is possible with a macro (perhaps parameterized macro?).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a shorter way to write compound 'if' conditions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39150884/is-there-a-shorter-way-to-write-compound-if-conditions)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because everything but the leftmost value in the `VOWELS` macro is *not* being tested against `c`.  What the macro expands to is:

```
c == 'a' || 'e' || ...
```

So basically, since a non-zero expression (i.e., the numeric value of the character `'e'`) is being tested for, that always evaluates to `1`.

What the macro should be is:

```
#define VOWEL(c) ((c) == 'a') || ((c) == 'e') || ((c) == 'i') || ((c) == 'o') || ((c) == 'u') || ((c) == 'A') || ((c) == 'E') || ((c) == 'I') || ((c) == 'O') || ((c) == 'U')
```

And then, you would simply use:

```
if(VOWEL(c))
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This will expand to

```
if(c == 'a' || 'e' || 'i' || 'o' || 'u' || 'A' || 'E' || 'I' || 'O' || 'U')
```

Which will check for `c==a` and then logical OR it with `e` which has a non zero value. So the result will always be TRUE.

What you want is

```
 #define VOWELCHECK(c) ((c)=='a') || ((c)=='e') || ((c)=='i') || \
                       ((c)=='o') || ((c)=='u') || ((c)=='A') || \
                       ((c)=='E') || ((c)=='I') || ((c)=='O') || ((c)=='U')))


// In the program
if (VOWELCHECK(c))
{
   printf("vowel = %c\n", c);
}
```